# Get name and profile information of current Uber rider using Uber API

Tags: uber-api

I am an Uber driver and I have a slideshow that plays during the trip. I would like to personalize it for each rider. Is there some way to get the name of the rider of the current trip via the driver or other API? I would also like to be able to find out if I have ever given a ride to the current rider in the past.

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not possible to associate a rider identity with the specific trip on your side. The best case is to use the /me endpoint and ask the user to sign in and give permission to share their profile information.